# XSLT - check if all nodes of a sequence match a set of values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

Using XSLT v2.0, how can I check that the text of all the selected nodes are matching some reference values?

For example, I select all `H1` nodes. I want to make sure that all of them are either equal to "The title" or "A heading".

I've been trying to create a function for that:

```
<xsl:function name="is-valid" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="seq" as="item()*" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$seq">
            <xsl:if test="not(matches(current()/text(),'The title|A heading'))">
                <!-- ??? -->           
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>
```

I'm don't think this is the way to go in XSLT, but I can't find how to do this.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 has an `every..satisfies` construct that can help here:

```
<xsl:function name="e:is-valid" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="s" as="item()*" />
  <xsl:value-of select="every $i in $s satisfies $i=('The title', 'A heading')"/>
</xsl:function>
```

---

Here's a complete example:

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r>
  <h1>Wrong title</h1>
  <h1>The title</h1>
  <h1>A heading</h1>
</r>
```

### XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:e="http://example.com/f">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:message>
      <xsl:value-of select="e:is-valid(//h1)"/>
    </xsl:message>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="e:is-valid" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="s" as="item()*" />
    <xsl:value-of select="every $i in $s satisfies $i=('The title','A heading')"/>
  </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is great, I had no idea about this syntax. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good solution, but you may want to correct the *version* attribute of *xsl:stylesheet* to 2.0.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Thanks, fixed.  And [nice v1.0 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36708263/290085).

Answer (score 3):

Just use this simple XPath expression -- [**the double negation law**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation#Double_negative_elimination):

```
not(h1[not(. = ('The title','A heading'))])
```

As a demonstration, given the same XML document as in the answer of @kjhughes:

```
<r>
  <h1>Wrong title</h1>
  <h1>The title</h1>
  <h1>A heading</h1>
</r>
```

this XSLT 2.0 transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="20"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:sequence select="not(h1[not(. = ('The title','A heading'))])"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the wanted, correct result:

```
false
```

---

This can be used in XPath 1.0 to determine if all the string-values of a node-set `$ns1` are among the string-values of another nodeset `$ns2` :

```
not(not($ns1[. = $ns2]))
```

Here is the XPath 1,0 / XSLT 1.0 equivalent of the XSLT 2.0 /XPath 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:param name="pValues">
   <v>The title</v>
   <v>A heading</v>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vValues" select="document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pValues']/*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="not(h1[not(. = $vValues)])"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, always very resourceful! Very interesting approach that will probably serve others as well.

Comment: @Flag, you are welcome. As for the "Double Negation Law", I believe they study it even as part of Philosophy :)